# Is it possible for send keys/keyboard to type the contents of one index on a list using python

Tags: python, keyboard, solidworks

I am working on python code to change specifications in thousands of Solidworks Drawing files. Id like to use the `Keyboard` function or something similar to send keys in VBA. I have all of the specifications stored in three different lists/arrays. It is possible to have send keys type out the contents of lets say the second index in my list?

I am new to python so i havent tried much. Just want some feedback on the viability of this strategy since time is not on my side for this deliverable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pyautogui might be a good match for your needs.
here is a quick examples of using it to type text from a list.
the sleep if for you to have time to focus on a text field.

```
import pyautogui
import time

my_list = ["this","is","a","list"]
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.typewrite(my_list[1])
```

[pyautogui documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: this worked well for me thank you. Now i just need to figure out how to do it for multiple iles one after the other ahaha! Wonderful solution thanks again sir wish i could upvote it.

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct if you are satisfied with it. Thanks